# How to pull a record from subquery1 to the subquery2, if that record does not exist in subquery2

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a subquery for each week 1 and week 2 of pricing data that contains a sku, store number, a regular price and an effective price, like this:

subquery1 =

```
week  sku  store_num  regular_price   effective_price
1     123       5456            1.99             1.99
1     456       5423            2.99              .99
1     789       6788            1.49             1.49
1     222       6577            1.79             1.49
```

subquery2 =

```
week  sku  store_num  regular_price   effective_price
2     123       5456            0.00             1.99
2     456       5423            1.79              .95
2     789       6788            0.00             0.00
2     888       3446            1.00             1.00
```

What I want to do is pull forward the regular and effective prices that were FOUND in subquery1 but NOT FOUND in subquery 2 (0.00). So I want my output to look like this:

output =

```
week  sku  store_num  regular_price   effective_price
2     123       5456            1.99             1.99
2     456       5423            1.79              .95
2     789       6788            1.49             1.49
2     888       3446            1.00             1.00
```

How can I go about doing this? I've tried using a case statement but I get stuck in the logic.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the values in subquery2 that are not 0, otherwise they are replaced with the values in subquery1.  This would be a bit simpler if you used `NULL` instead of `0` to represent missing values.

```
select week, sku, store_num,
       coalesce(nullif(s2.regular_price, 0), s1.regular_price) as regular_price,
       coalesce(nullif(s2.effective_price, 0), s1.effective_price) as effective_price
from (<subquery2>) s2 left join
     (<subquery1>) s1
     using (week, sku, store_num)
```